# Efficient base64 compression and serialization in .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm working on a legacy application built in .NET 1.1.

Part of the functionality is to take JPG and other attachments, and serialize them into a base64 string in an XML file.

Right now the implementation just uses the framework XmlSerializer and serializes the object containing the attachments, which in turn are also just stored as object.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OmdCds)); 
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(m_ExportLocation, m_XMLFileName + ".xml")); 
xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(tw);
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("cdsd", "cds_dt");
ns.Add("", "cds");
ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlTextWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"");
serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, m_Record, ns);
xmlTextWriter.Close();
tw.Close();
```

Nested way down in the m_Record object is the following object:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="cds_dt")]
public class content 
{
private object itemField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Media", typeof(byte[]), DataType="base64Binary")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TextContent", typeof(string))]
        public object Item 
        {
            get 
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set 
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is all extremely slow for large attachments, so I'm trying to figure out if this is the fastest way to write this to XML.

I'm also wondering if this compresses at the same time, or if I need to compress this base64 output separately?

Please keep in mind this in in .NET 1.1, and it is not an option to change the framework version. I'd also like to work within the confines of what the framework has to offer, unless I can get an incredible difference in speed from something 3rd party.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to compress a JPG.

Comment: @spender - Fair enough, but there are some other formats supported too. That said, the speed of file writing is really the issue. If compression won't solve it, I'm hoping there is simply a better way to do it. Also, hoping not to have to write a custom serializer as it is a massive object they are serializing!

Comment: If you're still actively maintaining a .NET 1.1 application, then you really should upgrade, at least to .NET 2.0 SP2. Is .NET 1.1 even _supported_ by Microsoft anymore?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - again, not an option to move out of .NET 1.1 for various reasons I can't get into. And no, 1.1 is NOT supported my MS anymore! I just need to know if this is the most efficient way to do it in 1.1